# how to remove the column that having a null value with min and max

Tags: sql-server

I want the all null values in my column to disappear or not be displayed. The not value in where didn't work for my code:

```
select A.EmpID [X_TMSHT_EMPID] ,convert (varchar,(A.[RecordDate]),1) [X_TMSHT_APPLY],  
  , (convert(varchar,(A.[RecordDate]),1) + ' ' +( MAX(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('O', A.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0,SUBSTRING(A.[Entries], LEN(A.[Entries]) - 5, 5), NULL)))) AS [TimeOut]
FROM Employees[B]
inner JOIN[DTR Upload] [A] ON B.EmployeeNo = A.EmpID 
GROUP by B.LastName, B.FirstName, B.MiddleName, A.EmpID, A.[recordDate] 
order by A.[recordDate] asc, B.LastName + ','+B.FirstName + ','+ B.MiddleName asc
```

[image: the null in time out the column disapear]

Comment: Can you share some table structure with data and what is your expected output.

Comment: ok wait a post a picture

Comment: in short i dont see the all null value

Comment: Please show the results you want to obtain (it can be hard to people to visualise what you want based on a description - much easier if you show us).

Comment: remove the 1 column because it is null this is i want the answer

Comment: As already asked please show us - text description isn't clear.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP is not helping with any data samples and what i understand is OP want to remove the Timeout which contains NULL value. So i just used the derived table to filter out the Timeout with NOT NULL value.

```
     SELECT * FROM (select A.EmpID [X_TMSHT_EMPID] ,convert (varchar,(A.[RecordDate]),1) [X_TMSHT_APPLY],  
      , (convert(varchar,(A.[RecordDate]),1) + ' ' +( MAX(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('O', A.[Entries], 0), -1) > 0,SUBSTRING(A.[Entries], LEN(A.[Entries]) - 5, 5), NULL)))) AS [TimeOut]
    FROM Employees[B]
    inner JOIN[DTR Upload] [A] ON B.EmployeeNo = A.EmpID 

    ) AS d
    WHERE d.TimeOut IS NOT NULL
GROUP by d.LastName, d.FirstName, d.MiddleName, d.EmpID, d.[recordDate]
    order by d.[recordDate] asc
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining what you have changed in the query to solve the answer the question.